# quarkus runtimeException "Bad type on operand stack"

Tags: java, jwt, quarkus

I have an error when creating a jwt token encoded in base 64.

The error that is returned is this one:

```
Caused by:**
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:142)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:248)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.createTestInstance(QuarkusTestExtension.java:390)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstanceFactory(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:285)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl1.zig:413)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/ciwara/kalanSowApp/security/TokenProvider.validateToken(Ljava/lang/String;)Z @42: invokeinterface
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Throwable'
```

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TokenProvider {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenProvider.class);

    @Inject
    private KalanSowAppConfiguration applicationConfiguration;



    private static final String AUTHORITIES_KEY = "auth";
    private Key key;
    private long tokenValidityInMilliseconds;
    private long tokenValidityInMillisecondsForRememberMe;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        byte[] keyBytes;
        String secret = applicationConfiguration.jwtConfiguration.base64Secret;

        if (secret == null || secret.trim().equals("")) {

            keyBytes = "".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            log.info("Using secret key", keyBytes);
        } else {
            log.info("Using a Base64-encoded JWT secret key");
            keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secret);
            log.info("Using a Base64-encoded JWT secret key", keyBytes);
        }

        this.key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
        this.tokenValidityInMilliseconds = 1000 * applicationConfiguration.jwtConfiguration.tokenValidityInSeconds;
        this.tokenValidityInMillisecondsForRememberMe = 1000
                * applicationConfiguration.jwtConfiguration.tokenValidityInSecondsForRememberMe;
    }

    public String createToken(JwtPrincipal principal, boolean rememberMe) {
        long now = (new Date()).getTime();
        Date validity;
        if (rememberMe) {
            validity = new Date(now + this.tokenValidityInMillisecondsForRememberMe);
        } else {
            validity = new Date(now + this.tokenValidityInMilliseconds);
        }

        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(principal.getName()).claim(AUTHORITIES_KEY, principal.getAuthorities())
                .signWith(this.key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512).setExpiration(validity).compact();
    }

    public Principal getPrincipal(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();

        String[] roles = null;
        if (claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY) != null) {
            Collection<String> authorities = Arrays.stream(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(","))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            roles = (String[]) authorities.toArray();
        }

        return new JwtPrincipal(claims.getSubject(), roles);
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String authToken) throws ExceptionInInitializerError {
        try {

            // OK, we can trust this JWT
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (io.jsonwebtoken.security.SecurityException | MalformedJwtException e) {
            // don't trust the JWT!
            log.info("Invalid JWT signature.");
            log.trace("Invalid JWT signature trace: {}", e);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            log.info("Expired JWT token.");
            log.trace("Expired JWT token trace: {}", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            log.info("Unsupported JWT token.");
            log.trace("Unsupported JWT token trace: {}", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.info("JWT token compact of handler are invalid.");
            log.trace("JWT token compact of handler are invalid trace: {}", e);
        }
          // don't trust the JWT!
           return false;
    }
}
```

I don't understang where is a problem of bad type on operand stack issue.

> Config class is

```
@ConfigProperties(prefix = "application")
public class KalanSowAppConfiguration {

    public JwtConfiguration jwtConfiguration = new JwtConfiguration();

    @ConfigProperties(prefix = "application.jwtConfiguration")
    public static class JwtConfiguration {
        @ConfigProperty(name = "base64-secret")
        public String base64Secret;

        @ConfigProperty(name = "tokenValidityInSeconds", defaultValue = "300")
        public long tokenValidityInSeconds;

        @ConfigProperty(name = "tokenValidityInSecondsForRememberMe", defaultValue = "7200")
        public long tokenValidityInSecondsForRememberMe;
    }


    public JwtConfiguration getJwtConfiguration() {
        return jwtConfiguration;
    }

    public void setJwtConfiguration(JwtConfiguration jwtConfiguration) {
        this.jwtConfiguration = jwtConfiguration;
    }



}
```

> Configuration class read application.properties file. properties file contain the secret key  and base64Secret to generate token.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ciwara.kalanSowApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>kalanSow-Backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
        <quarkus.version>0.26.1</quarkus.version>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <jboss-logging.version>3.3.2.Final</jboss-logging.version>
        <nimbus-jose.version>8.4</nimbus-jose.version>
        <mockito.version>3.2.4</mockito.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${nimbus-jose.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-jdbc-h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-jdbc-h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-test-h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-metrics</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-spring-di</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <!--    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.7</version>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>native-image</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <enableHttpUrlHandler>true</enableHttpUrlHandler>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemProperties>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                    </systemProperties>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <junit.includes>**/*Test.java</junit.includes>
                <junit.excludes>**/*Test.java</junit.excludes>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Which config did you use to build your native image ?

Comment: Hello Ben, I added  my config class. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I mean which build options did you use to build your image in your pom.xml for quarkus-maven-plugin or in your application.properties 
The additionalBuildsArgs used by graalvm

Comment: I added pom.xml  if you want to know  what  quarkus-maven plugin I am use